# How do I fix my camera's xRotation's Clamping?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, clamp

I made a first person camera using parts of Brackeys Guide, I have camera moving on both the axis but the line for the xRotation clamp doesn't work when I run the game. How can I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{   
    
        public float mouseSensitivity = 200f;

        public Transform playerBody;
        public Transform cam;
        private float xRotation = 0f;
        
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;     // stops you from click out off the sceen
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;    // mouse imput
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;    // mouse imput
    

        xRotation = mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80f, 73f);  // stops you from breaking your neck
        

        Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);  // left and right movement
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);  // left and right movement 
        cam.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);  // up and down movement
       
        
    }
```

Setting new specific variables like roty and rotx, and clamping them individually.

Comment: Is there a problem with this method Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the Vector3 vector has no value, if a value is generated, it can be

```
    private  Vector3 m_Dir
    void  Update () {
    this.m_Dir =  new  Vector3 (localRotation, Vector3.up * mouseX,  
    tVector3.left * mouseY); 
    playerBody.Rotate(m_Dir);
    cam.Rotate(m_Dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in the `Update` method:

1. `xRotation = mouseY` is not correct, since `mouseY` represents the ***delta*** angle you want to rotate in this frame, while `xRotation` represents the ***current*** angle at which the camera is rotated. You have to do a sum to get the next pitch of the camera, so `xRotation += mouseY`.
2. The quaternion `localRotation` is created but not actually used in the rotating logic, you still rotate the camera with `cam.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY)`. Replace it with `cam.localRotation = localRotation`.

The final code should look like this:

```
float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

// note: you shouldn't hardcode the min and max values,
//       use some values that you can change in the inspector
xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation + mouseY, -80f, 73f);

cam.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
```

Comment: Your answer is quite convincing, thank you for answering this question